# If $A$ and $B$ are proper ideals of a ring with no zero divisors, show that $A\cap B \neq \{0\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> If $A$ and $B$ are proper ideals of a ring with no zero divisors, show that $A\cap B \neq \{0\}$

**Ideals:** 
A subset $I$ of a ring $R$ is called an ideal if

1. $I$ is a subring of $R$
2. For all $a\in I,r\in R$ $ar\in I$ and $ra\in I$.

$A$ and $B$  both satisfy the above. How to show that $A\cap B \neq 0$?

Comment: $ 0\neq \{0\} $

Comment: @Antoine Thanks. edited my problem

Comment: "Proper" apparently also meant to entail "nonzero", it seems

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

If $a\in A$ and $b\in B$, where is $ab$?

Comment: $ab\in A$ and $ ab\in B$ then  $ab\in A\cap B$